# Magento 2 - How to make a event based module in back end?

Tags: magento2

How Can I perform this event: if some one from Magento admin delete any customer then write a log which admin user delete that customer and date and time of the action.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a plugin for `Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User` class

> **di.xml**
>
> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User">
             <plugin name="delete_user_action" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\User\Delete" sortOrder="1"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

> **Delete.php**
>
> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/User/Delete.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\User;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Delete
{

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    public function aroundDelete(\Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User $user, callable $proceed, $object)
    {
        $object->load($object->getId());

        $result = $proceed($object);
        $object->afterDelete();

        $this->logger->debug('START :-'.__METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);

        if ($this->authSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $adminUserName = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUserName();
        }

        $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
        $message = sprintf(' %s has Deleted Customer', $adminUserName);
        $this->logger->debug($date. ' => '.$message);       

        $this->logger->debug('END :-'.__METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you  let me implement the code and if I face any issue I will let you know.

Comment: One small query do I have to create the virtual type within di.xml I am learning this for the first time and not so clear about the concepts.

Comment: no just `<type>` i  have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Hi I implemented the code but if I run s:d:c its giving an error that the delete file does not exist

Comment: can you share whole error?

Comment: did you `cache:flush` ?

Comment: In PluginList.php line 182:
                                                           
  Plugin class Naiwrita\\Plugin\User\Delete doesn't exist  
                                               This is the error performed c;f

Comment: you added extra slash in your path `Naiwrita\\Plugin\User\Delete` add this `Naiwrita\Plugin\User\Delete`

Comment: First I also thought the same but I used 
namespace Naiwrita\Boral\Plugin\User;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: No I meant earlier it was this only. I didnt change anything

Comment: it should be your `Vendor\Module\Plugin\User;`

Comment: Yes I got it wrong in the di.xml. now after running the code where should I check the result

Comment: If I delete one customer from the customer list in admin panel and then where can I check the result

Comment: you can check in /var/log folder

Comment: in that folder will a separate log file will get generated? since it contains connector.log that is empty. system.log does not contain any related info and debug.log has the last line as :  cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://10.0.0.249/naiwrita/mage1/admin/customer/index/delete/id/2/key/8de4d0ffde1771281221757bb4f509886a5cc11d12a98cecd791e03c8eab516a/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"notification_update_customer_session_2"}} []

Comment: you can see in debug.log

Comment: but the last line of the debug log shows this (I posted in the above comment)

Comment: is it possible to create a new log file

Comment: are you getting a log...? yes it's possible to create a new log file

Comment: yes getting a log

Comment: you can mark it as accepted answer if it's solved your issue so it could help others and you can ask another question for creating log file, I can answer that.

Comment: Ok sure. I will do that.

Comment: In the debug file why is it showing: DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://10.0.0.249/naiwrita/mage1/admin/customer/index/delete/id/3/key. is it the error

Comment: no i don't think that's an error

Comment: ok then thank you so much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96169/discussion-on-answer-by-mohit-rane-magento-2-how-to-make-a-event-based-module).